# Can't get Future Value from DIO Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm really new in Flutter programming. I've problem while try to get value from Future.  After I get it, I want to deserialize it for further processing.
The return value from the Future is on JSON Array.

What should I do to solve this situation?

```
class _MyAppState extends State<BodyWidget>
{
  bool loading = true;
  List<Widget> listArray = [];
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  dynamic isicontent = null;

  Future<dynamic> getOrderHistory() async {
    final String pathUrl = "http://p.q.r.s/mobile/QIXGetShipmentHistory/" + await FlutterSession().get("MobileUsername");
    var responseDio = await dio.get(pathUrl, options: Options( headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' } ) );

    print(responseDio.data);  // It's works fine here...
    return responseDio.data;
  }


void renderIconShipmentOrderHistory()
  {
     var resultRespon = getOrderHistory();
     print(resultRespon);   //the problem is here...
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the response printed data ```print(responseDio.data)``` on your question

Comment: You're not returning any `Future`, to begin with and therefore violate the method signature.

Comment: The response from (responseDio.data)  -->  Future<Response<dynamic>>

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement needs to return a `Future`; something alike:

```
return dio.get(
    pathUrl,
    options: Options(
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    )
)
```

The `async` keyword from the signature likely can be removed, as there is no more `await`.

Obviously, not returning a `Future` but awaiting the result may be the other option.